# search a string/number in memory using gdb?

Tags: gdb

Say I have following integer `int i = 18723849;`

So is there any parameter in GDB that can help search memory to find above integer and it's memory location?

E.g: `(gdb) find 18723849`

Answer (score 1):

> So is there any parameter in GDB that can help search memory to find above integer

Yes, [there is](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Searching-Memory.html).

It's also the first hit for https://www.google.com/search?q=gdb+search+memory